# Как в классе NpgsqlDataReader, достать правильно дату и время (библиотека Npgsql.dll)?

Tags: c#, postgresql, datetime

У меня последний пакет библиотеки [Npgsql.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/4.1.3.1#show-github-usage).
Данные типа int, string и double 
я достаю так :

```
(reader.IsDBNull (0)) ? default (int) : reader.GetInt16 (0);
(reader.IsDBNull (9)) ? default (string) : reader.GetString (9);
```

У меня в Postgres Есть поле даты (arrivaltime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой метод Get у NpgsqlDataReader достаёт дату?
Так и так не получается достать :

```
(reader.IsDBNull (4)) ? default (DateTime) : reader.DateTime (4);
(reader.IsDBNull (2)) ? default (DateTime) : reader.Timestamp (2);
```

Ошибка:

```
error CS1061: 'IDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'DateTime' and no accessible extension method 'DateTime' accepting a first argument of type 'IDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: `GetDateTime` ?

Comment: @Exploding Kitten да вроде ошибка ушла , но в выпадающем списке не было этого метода ... надо бы проверить скомпилируется или нет